# Intersect two json arrays and combine all fields without using explicitly naming fields to combine

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, fetch, intersection

I have converted two excel sheets to json using a free online tool. It creates two separate json properties for each sheet. So we have the following json example:

```
{
  "Product Info": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Fuel Source": "Wood",
      "Type": "Freestanding",
      "Model": "F1150",
      "Catalytic": "No",
      "Maximum BTU's Per Hour": 55000,
      "Higher Heating Value Efficiency (HHV)": 0.7,
      "Lower Heating Value Efficiency (LHV)": 0.75,
      "Steady-State Efficiency": "n/a",
      "Link To Unit": "http://www.regency-fire.com/en/Products/Wood/Wood-Stoves/F1150",
      "Key Features": "Large fire viewing area, with heat radiating ceramic glass\nWood-finished handle\nHeavy duty cast hinges that will never bend or break\nSolid forged steel adjustable cam lock ensures a tight door seal over time\nFront mounted air adjustment\nAir operating safety tool\nHigh performance brick-lined firebox reflects heat\nNon-obtrusive air wash curtain keeps glass clean\nHeavy gauge steel log retainers to stop logs from rolling\nWelded ash lip will never bend or break\nRear heat deflector allowing for closer clearances\nMobile home and alcove approved\nDual-burn design creates longer and more complete burns\nBacked by the industry’s most comprehensive Limited Lifetime Warranty",
      "Product Size": "Small",
      "Maximum Log Size": "18\"",
      "Burn Time*": "Up to 8 hours",
      "Firebox Capacity": "1.3 cu. ft.",
      "Hopper Size": "n/a",
      "Emissions (g/hr)": "1.7 g/hr",
      "View Area": "126 sq. in.",
      "Exhaust Size": "6\"",
      "Minimum Fireplace Opening (W x H x D)": "n/a",
      "Fireplace Dimensions (W x H x D)": "24\" x 32-3/16\" x 20\"",
      "Picture Name": "F1150.jpg",
      "Feature Sheet File Name": "F1150 Feature Sheet.pdf",
      "Description": "The Regency Classic Small Wood Stove is perfect for smaller spaces, or for those needing to supplement their current heating system. It's compact footprint does not disappoint in heating capacity; burning efficiently, and extracting all the heat possible from one load of wood. Turn down your furnace and save money with this Regency small wood stove.",
      "Teaser": "A perfect fit for smaller rooms.  This small non-catalytic wood stove, comes with your choice of pedestal or legs and it is available in black or with nickel accents.",
      "Additional Picture Name #1": "F1150-B.jpg",
      "Pricing Reference Name": "001-915"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Fuel Source": "Wood",
      "Type": "Freestanding",
      "Model": "F2450",
      "Catalytic": "No",
      "Maximum BTU's Per Hour": 75000,
      "Higher Heating Value Efficiency (HHV)": 0.733,
      "Lower Heating Value Efficiency (LHV)": 78.4,
      "Steady-State Efficiency": "n/a",
      "Link To Unit": "http://www.regency-fire.com/en/Products/Wood/Wood-Stoves/F2450",
      "Key Features": "Large fire viewing area, with heat radiating ceramic glass\nWood-finished handle\nHeavy duty cast hinges that will never bend or break\nSolid forged steel adjustable cam lock ensures a tight door seal over time\nFront mounted air adjustment\nAir operating safety tool\nHigh performance brick-lined firebox reflects heat\nNon-obtrusive air wash curtain keeps glass clean\nWelded ash lip will never bend or break\nRear heat deflector allowing for closer clearances\nMobile home and alcove approved\nDual-burn design creates longer and more complete burns\nBacked by the industry’s most comprehensive Limited Lifetime Warranty",
      "Product Size": "Medium",
      "Maximum Log Size": "18\"",
      "Burn Time*": "Up to 10 hours",
      "Firebox Capacity": "2.3 cu. ft.",
      "Hopper Size": "n/a",
      "Emissions (g/hr)": "2.3 g/hr",
      "View Area": "161 sq. in.",
      "Exhaust Size": "6\"",
      "Minimum Fireplace Opening (W x H x D)": "n/a",
      "Fireplace Dimensions (W x H x D)": "24\" x 36-5/16\" x 27-3/16\"",
      "Picture Name": "F2450.jpg",
      "Feature Sheet File Name": "F2450 Feature Sheet.pdf",
      "Description": "The Regency Classic Medium Wood Stove provides the perfect amount of heat for most spaces. Load wood in this stove front to back or side to side for the optimum convenience. Backed by our Limited Lifetime Warranty, we are confident that the quality workmanship, finest materials and durable construction of all Regency products, will serve your family for years to come.",
      "Teaser": "The F2450 is a Medium non-catalytic wood stove, comes with your choice of pedestal or legs and it is available in black or with nickel accents.",
      "Additional Picture Name #1": "F2450-B.jpg",
      "Additional Picture Name #2": "F2450-C.jpg",
      "Pricing Reference Name": "001-946"
    }
  ],
  "Company Pricing": [
    {
      "Part Num": "001-915",
      "Part Description": "Gravity Air Kit Z2510/FP90/CF780",
      "Prod Group": "08-WOOD",
      "MSPR USD": 975
    },
    {
      "Part Num": "001-946",
      "Part Description": "Adaptor Air Cool Chimney Sec FTF8",
      "Prod Group": "08-WOOD",
      "MSPR USD": 76
    }
  ]
}
```

These two properties are returned in the follow fetch request:

```
  const getProductInfo = async () => {
    isLoading.value = true;
    return  await useFetch(window.location.origin + '/assets/json/data.json', {
      onRequestError({ request, options, error }) {
        console.log(error);
        isLoading.value = false;
      },
      onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
        products.value = response._data;
        console.log(response._data)
        isLoading.value = false;
      },
      onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
        console.log(request.error);
        isLoading.value = false;
      }
    });
  };
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to merge these two together to one property such that I have a clean array with all of the properties of Product Info and include the fields from the Company pricing sheet. I believe this is called a left join on Product Info. The key between the two is "Pricing Reference Name" and "Part Num". I would do a for loop and and push each field if there is a match but i figure there has to be a more efficient way and without naming each field as these could change over time but I want this function to return everything. I am not sure if there is a way doing this with the ... notation to bring all fields over?

Either way I cannot find an example on stack with this exact request so hopefully this is doable.

Comment: Convert one of the arrays to an object whose keys are the linking property values. Then you can loop through the other array, find the related property in the object, and merge the objects with `{...obj1, ...obj2}`

Comment: @Barmar i think he is expecting that there cannot be any common key, instead there can be different key but few of them may have same value. 
Not sure how he is planning to do intersection

Comment: @brk He said **The key between the two is "Pricing Reference Name" and "Part Num"** That's the common key.

Comment: @Barmar then in next line he mentioned that **and without naming each field as these could change over time**

Comment: @brk I think OP is referring to the fields *other than* "Pricing Reference Name" and "Part Num"

Comment: @Nick I think that's talking about all the other properties that need to be copied into the result. And that's handled automatically by `...`.

Comment: @Irish Redneck please clarify if these **"Pricing Reference Name" and "Part Num"** can also change

Comment: @Barmar exactly, that's what I meant, I was referring to the fields whose name could change over time

Comment: If "Pricing Reference Name" and "Part Num" can also change this problem is insoluble. There has to be a fixed join key or the code has to be rewritten every time.

Comment: Nick and Barmar are correct. My question possibly could have been clearer though. But yea I am assuming the key names wont change and if they do I could easily manage those two and adjust the code.

Comment: I have updated my question. The correct term would be a left join on Product Info and adding the fields from company pricing to the Product info array basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to iterate the `Company Pricing` into a `Map` based on `Part Num` and then iterate the `Product Info`, using the `Pricing Reference Name` to lookup the appropriate pricing in that Map:

```js
const products = {
  "Product Info": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Fuel Source": "Wood",
      "Type": "Freestanding",
      "Model": "F1150",
      "Catalytic": "No",
      "Maximum BTU's Per Hour": 55000,
      "Higher Heating Value Efficiency (HHV)": 0.7,
      "Lower Heating Value Efficiency (LHV)": 0.75,
      "Steady-State Efficiency": "n/a",
      "Link To Unit": "http://www.regency-fire.com/en/Products/Wood/Wood-Stoves/F1150",
      "Key Features": "Large fire viewing area, with heat radiating ceramic glass\nWood-finished handle\nHeavy duty cast hinges that will never bend or break\nSolid forged steel adjustable cam lock ensures a tight door seal over time\nFront mounted air adjustment\nAir operating safety tool\nHigh performance brick-lined firebox reflects heat\nNon-obtrusive air wash curtain keeps glass clean\nHeavy gauge steel log retainers to stop logs from rolling\nWelded ash lip will never bend or break\nRear heat deflector allowing for closer clearances\nMobile home and alcove approved\nDual-burn design creates longer and more complete burns\nBacked by the industry’s most comprehensive Limited Lifetime Warranty",
      "Product Size": "Small",
      "Maximum Log Size": "18\"",
      "Burn Time*": "Up to 8 hours",
      "Firebox Capacity": "1.3 cu. ft.",
      "Hopper Size": "n/a",
      "Emissions (g/hr)": "1.7 g/hr",
      "View Area": "126 sq. in.",
      "Exhaust Size": "6\"",
      "Minimum Fireplace Opening (W x H x D)": "n/a",
      "Fireplace Dimensions (W x H x D)": "24\" x 32-3/16\" x 20\"",
      "Picture Name": "F1150.jpg",
      "Feature Sheet File Name": "F1150 Feature Sheet.pdf",
      "Description": "The Regency Classic Small Wood Stove is perfect for smaller spaces, or for those needing to supplement their current heating system. It's compact footprint does not disappoint in heating capacity; burning efficiently, and extracting all the heat possible from one load of wood. Turn down your furnace and save money with this Regency small wood stove.",
      "Teaser": "A perfect fit for smaller rooms.  This small non-catalytic wood stove, comes with your choice of pedestal or legs and it is available in black or with nickel accents.",
      "Additional Picture Name #1": "F1150-B.jpg",
      "Pricing Reference Name": "001-915"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Fuel Source": "Wood",
      "Type": "Freestanding",
      "Model": "F2450",
      "Catalytic": "No",
      "Maximum BTU's Per Hour": 75000,
      "Higher Heating Value Efficiency (HHV)": 0.733,
      "Lower Heating Value Efficiency (LHV)": 78.4,
      "Steady-State Efficiency": "n/a",
      "Link To Unit": "http://www.regency-fire.com/en/Products/Wood/Wood-Stoves/F2450",
      "Key Features": "Large fire viewing area, with heat radiating ceramic glass\nWood-finished handle\nHeavy duty cast hinges that will never bend or break\nSolid forged steel adjustable cam lock ensures a tight door seal over time\nFront mounted air adjustment\nAir operating safety tool\nHigh performance brick-lined firebox reflects heat\nNon-obtrusive air wash curtain keeps glass clean\nWelded ash lip will never bend or break\nRear heat deflector allowing for closer clearances\nMobile home and alcove approved\nDual-burn design creates longer and more complete burns\nBacked by the industry’s most comprehensive Limited Lifetime Warranty",
      "Product Size": "Medium",
      "Maximum Log Size": "18\"",
      "Burn Time*": "Up to 10 hours",
      "Firebox Capacity": "2.3 cu. ft.",
      "Hopper Size": "n/a",
      "Emissions (g/hr)": "2.3 g/hr",
      "View Area": "161 sq. in.",
      "Exhaust Size": "6\"",
      "Minimum Fireplace Opening (W x H x D)": "n/a",
      "Fireplace Dimensions (W x H x D)": "24\" x 36-5/16\" x 27-3/16\"",
      "Picture Name": "F2450.jpg",
      "Feature Sheet File Name": "F2450 Feature Sheet.pdf",
      "Description": "The Regency Classic Medium Wood Stove provides the perfect amount of heat for most spaces. Load wood in this stove front to back or side to side for the optimum convenience. Backed by our Limited Lifetime Warranty, we are confident that the quality workmanship, finest materials and durable construction of all Regency products, will serve your family for years to come.",
      "Teaser": "The F2450 is a Medium non-catalytic wood stove, comes with your choice of pedestal or legs and it is available in black or with nickel accents.",
      "Additional Picture Name #1": "F2450-B.jpg",
      "Additional Picture Name #2": "F2450-C.jpg",
      "Pricing Reference Name": "001-946"
    }
  ],
  "Company Pricing": [
    {
      "Part Num": "001-915",
      "Part Description": "Gravity Air Kit Z2510/FP90/CF780",
      "Prod Group": "08-WOOD",
      "MSPR USD": 975
    },
    {
      "Part Num": "001-946",
      "Part Description": "Adaptor Air Cool Chimney Sec FTF8",
      "Prod Group": "08-WOOD",
      "MSPR USD": 76
    }
  ]
}

const pricing = new Map(products['Company Pricing'].map(o => [o['Part Num'], o]))

const result = products['Product Info'].map(o => ({ ...o, ...pricing.get(o['Pricing Reference Name']), }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does seem to work but I think the technical term I am looking for is a left join. I really only want Product Info with the additional terms added from the other. So for product info that array is 128 products total and the other Company pricing is 1288. So really I would only have 128 after the join. I apologize as I wasnt realizing this is a left join. I have updated my question!

Comment: Technically if I just flip and do result first then info does that work?

Comment: I believe my modification of your code works but please confirm. If you agree I will accept this answer as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @IrishRedneck I suspected you might want a left join of some type, but I guessed the wrong way. What you propose is correct and I've updated my answer to match